# isabelle - Choose an arbitrary but fixed element

Tags: isabelle

How can an arbitrary but fixed element be selected from a set in Isabelle? The element selected will be used as random element from the set for further processing, but no other element must be used further.

My first attempt was:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main Orderings
begin 
  value "(let el ∈ {3::int, 4, 5} in el)"
end
```

But gives a syntax error.

My second attempt was:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main Orderings
begin 
   value "(let el = (SOME x . x ∈  {{3::int, 4}, 
                                    {5::int, 6} , 
                                    {7::int, 8}}) 
                  in el)" 
end
```

giving a type `int set` and not the expected type `int`.

**Edit 1**

A new example:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main Orderings
begin 

fun add :: "int set ⇒ int" where
  "add st = (let el = (SOME x . x ∈ st) in el + (10::int))"

value "add {3::int, 4, 5, 6}"

end
```

The result of the code is:

```
"(SOME u. 3 = u ∨ 4 = u ∨ 5 = u ∨ 6 = u) + 10"
  :: "int"
```

instead of an integer value. How do I write `add` so that the results is either 13, 14, 15 or 16? The exact value does not matter, it must just be different each time the function is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you got an `int set` as result is that you select an element from an `int set set`. In your second attempt, instead of using a "flat" set, you have used a nested set.

Apart from your specific question, I would recommend you look at the `folding` locale in the `Finite_Set` theory. It provides a combinator for folding over sets (given that the operator commutes).

Answer (score 1):

You can define

```
definition "el = (SOME x. x ∈ {(3::int), 4, 5})"
```

You can then prove e.g.

```
lemma "el ∈ {3,4,5}"
  unfolding el_def by (rule someI_ex) auto
```

Logically, `el` is some fixed element of `{3, 4, 5}` (as we just proved), and it is *always* the same element – but you don't know which one. You can think of it as ‘When the universe came into existence, it chose a value for `SOME x. x ∈ {3,4,5}`, either `3`, `4`, or `5`, but it will never tell you which one it is.’

I don't know what it is exactly that you are trying to do, but I do not think that this is what you really want to do. Perhaps you can go into a bit more detail as to what you want to do with this element?

Comment: For the example say that the selected element will be passed to a function that doubles the value. I need to know the value that was selected.

In c++ I will create a list of the set, select a random index and return the value at that index.

Comment: But what for? What do you actually want to prove?

Comment: I want to described a data flow network and prove if the network satisfy some properties, some other property will also be valid. The selection of an element is related when I want to see how data flow through the network.